# Cannot connect to host(sftp) in phpseclip

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I have to connect to client sftp to upload data.
Here is my code to connect to client sftp :

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('some ip', 22);
        if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) 
        {
            exit('Login Failed');
        }
```

but i get this error "Cannot connect to host. Banner timeout in SSH2.php on line 800"

the SSH2.php line 800 is :

```
user_error(rtrim("Cannot connect to $host. Banner timeout"), E_USER_NOTICE);
```

and can anyone explain this description :

> on windows this returns a "Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected" error

the description showed above the line 800 SSH2.php

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what version you're using. You're clearly not using the latest 2.0 version:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.11/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L800

Nor are you using the latest 1.0 version:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0.11/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L800

It's not reasonable to expect people who might be able to help you to have to brute force every single version to figure out the one that has `user_error(rtrim("Cannot connect to $host. Banner timeout"), E_USER_NOTICE);` on line 800.

That said, I do note that no current version says `Banner timeout`. The closest line to that that I could find was this one:

```
user_error(rtrim("Cannot connect to $host. Error $errno. $errstr"));
```

(`$errno` and `$errstr` come from fsockopen, in this case)

I did some digging. It looks like "Banner Timeout" hasn't been in the error message for at least 3.5 years:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/23c65c383945cfc9c2293f45a7cbc6f1a68178ec#diff-82a5983a6daace4acbcc65edf2dfb605

So that's at least how old your phpseclib installation is. It's possibly even older than that. So I'd recommend upgrading.